# Autodesk Forge Viewer : Translate Rvt, DWG File, Download It's SVF and Load SVF in the Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

We are trying to do the following :

- upload a .rvt, dwg file to oss
- start model translation of this rvt file

What we want :

Now once translation is finished

- Download svf and its reference file and save to s3
- Load svf file into viewer with s3 url

Need help with :

- **How we can get SVF and its reference files after the model translation is completed?**

Answer (score 0):

We don't have formal API support for downloading SVF derivative files, but we have some samples devastating this possibility. Please try to search `Extract SVF` on https://aps.autodesk.com/blog, then you will find that. For example:

- https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs
- https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/php-sample-extract-svf
- https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-c-net

Ref: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+aps.autodesk.com%2Fblog+extract+svf&oq=site%3A+aps.autodesk.com%2Fblog+extract+svf&aqs=edge..69i57j69i58j69i64.8583j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8